# "Curious X": X is the subject or an object

Tags: verbs, word-usage

When *'curious'* is used as an adjective (e.g., in the construction *"A is a curious B"*), there is ambiguity as to whether the noun it modifies is:-

- **The subject:** *A* feels curious (e.g., *"Humans are a curious species"* meaning humans want to know about everything)
- **An object:** *A* is an object of curiosity (e.g., *"Dung beetles are a curious species"* meaning dung beetles are interesting to us)

How can we resolve this ambiguity? Is there an official way to do it? Both are correct 'de facto' as both versions of usage are common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You resolve the ambiguity by understanding the semantics.  It is not a matter of syntax.

*Curious* modifies *species* in both cases. It just means something quite different in the one case compared with what it means in the other.

It never applies to the subject. And that is not an object, since *be* is not transitive.

Comment: Thanks. 1) How come there isn't a specific way to address the 2 different meanings? 2) What does 'that' refer to in in your last point?

Comment: @YatharthROCK Because everyone can tell whether you mean inquisitive or interesting.  And that refers to *species*, which is not an object because *be* is not transitive.